# WMI Callback for Invoking Method in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to receive "On Progress" events when Syncronize method is invoked on Win32_OfflineFiles cache in PowerShell v3 (I'm restricted from using later version). According to MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309189(v=vs.85).aspx) the process is:

> To monitor progress, implement a WMI event sink to receive
>   SWbem.OnProgress event notifications. The strMessage parameter
>   contains a text string that is encoded with the following
>   colon-delimited format...

The PowerShell examples to receive a WMI event provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) I can't see how they could be translated to my use case.

Example snippet from a VBScript which works:

```
Set objCache         = objWMIServices.Get("Win32_OfflineFilesCache=@")
Set objParams        = objCache.Methods_("Synchronize").InParameters.SpawnInstance_
Set objSink          = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "SINK_")

objParams.Paths = ItemPaths
objWMIServices.ExecMethodAsync objSink, "Win32_OfflineFilesCache", "Synchronize", objParams, wbemFlagSendStatus

Sub SINK_OnProgress(UpperBound, Current, Message, objContext)
  ' process here
End Sub

Sub SINK_OnCompleted(HResult, objLastError, objContext)
 ' process here
End Sub
```

While I can see Register-CimIndication, Register-WMIEvent can be used for WMI event, and Register-ObjectEvent for .NET objects I can't see example how this works with invoking WMI methods, as Register-WMIEvent takes a WMI event class or WMI event query.

Current PowerShell code with no callback:

```
 $offlineCache = ([WmiClass]"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_OfflineFilesCache")
 $offlineCache.Synchronize($filesToSync,$OfflineFilesSyncControlFlagSyncOut+$OfflineFilesSyncControlCrKeepLatest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using [ManagementOperationObserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementoperationobserver(v=vs.110).aspx) and [InvokeMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt0aczf8(v=vs.110).aspx) with [Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-5.1)

$filesToSync contains an array of files to sync.

```
$OfflineFilesSyncControlFlagSyncOut = 0x00000004
$OfflineFilesSyncControlCrKeepLatest = 0x30000000
$OfflineFilesTransitionFlagConsole = 0x00000002
$offlineCache = ([WmiClass]"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_OfflineFilesCache")
    $offlineCache.Enable($true)
    $offlineCache.TransitionOnline([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($filesToSync[0]),$OfflineFilesTransitionFlagConsole)

    $observer = New-Object System.Management.ManagementOperationObserver

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $observer -EventName "Progress" -Action {
        param ($o,$e)
        Write-Host "Progress $($e.Current) of $($e.Upperbound) Result $($e.Message)"
    }

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $observer -EventName "Completed" -Action {
       param($o,$e)
       Write-Host "Progress $($e.Current) of $($e.Upperbound) Result $($e.Message)"
    }

    $params = $offlineCache.GetMethodParameters("Synchronize")
    $params.Paths = $filesToSync
    $params.Flags = $OfflineFilesSyncControlFlagSyncOut+$OfflineFilesSyncControlCrKeepLatest
    $offlineCache.InvokeMethod($observer,"Synchronize",$params,$null)
```

Comment: Old post, but do you mind posting more of the complete solution?

Comment: @user3010406 If you get WMI exception you may not have sufficient privilege, can try elevated. change $filesToSync[0] to desired filename.